# JavaFX native packaging with an external resources folder

Tags: java, plugins, groovy, jar, javafx

I currently have a large Java program built using Swing and I am exploring the possibility of migrating to JavaFX. I am particularly interested in the ability to support native packaging since my current configuration involves simply double-clicking an executable JAR file and I find that many of my users are confused by this. Here is my problem: my program uses a plugin architecture in which, upon launching, it discovers various tools contained in JAR files and Groovy scripts. Because the end user can add their own tools by adding their own JAR library or script file the tools must exist in a folder outside of my main JAR. The folder must be discoverable by the end-user such that they could add/modify these files themselves. Here is my current configuration:

./ - the root of the program

|__ main.jar

|__ Resources folder containing JAR libraries and script files

This flexible configuration also allowed for the program to simply be copied into new locations without requiring a proper setup. So, I ask, is there any way of maintaining this type of open configuration while using the native packaging utilities that are now available? Would I need to create a resources folder outside the location of the JAR itself during some kind of setup? If this is the case, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: What tools did you use to load plugins in your application before you start migrating to JavaFX? You can try to use `-Djava.ext.dirs` to load your plugins from external folder.

Comment: @SimY4 I have a custom developed process for loading plugin tools when the program launches. It works quite well at the moment.